# Update live plot in SLOW loop without plot greying out

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

Sometimes, I do live updates to a plot in a loop. Normally, this works fine, but when the processing within the loop takes a long time, the plot 'greys out'/sleeps, for all but the first 10 seconds of this time. This can be quite annoying, as it makes it typically not possible to distinguish the curves (I could use dotted lines of course, but...). I'm using Ubuntu, and about 10 seconds is the threshold where this starts to happen for me.

Below is some toy code to reproduce the problem, and some pictures to demonstrate what happens.

Is there an easy way to prevent this 'greying out' behaviour?

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as p
import time

def create_data(i):
    time.sleep(10)  # INCREASE THIS VALUE TO MAKE THE PLOT GREY OUT WHILE IT WAITS
    return np.sin(np.arange(i) * 0.1)

def live_plot(y):
    p.cla()
    p.plot(y)
    p.plot(y**2)
    p.draw()
    p.pause(0.01)

for i in xrange(1000):
    y = create_data(i)
    live_plot(y)
```

[image]

Comment: Might be worth a shot to run the first call to matplotlib in a new thread...

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the GUI window becomes non-responsive from the PoV of the window manager so it 'helpfully' grays it out to tell you this.  There may be a setting in gnome/unity (not sure which you are using) to disable this. (system dependent, maybe impossible :( )

One solution is to push the computation to another thread/process which will allow you to use a blocking `show` to leave the GUI main loop responsive. (complex :( )

Another solution is to in your slow loop periodically poke the GUI loop.  I think calling `fig.canvas.flush_events()` should be sufficient. (dirty :( )

In short, GUIs (and asynchronous stuff in general) are hard to get right.

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu 18.04, go to "search program" and type in "compiz" in the search box. When the ccsm window comes up, look for and uncheck the "fade window" box.